# What does MAMP do?

Tags: magento, mamp, mamp-pro

I have to develop api and maintain 'MAGENTO'...
I'm new to this so my senior told me to 'test' our service locally after checking out the all source code.

So I'm searching how to do this...
What I found is the combination of magento and mamp...
But due to the lack of understanding of magento, I don't know what mamp does for my purpose.

Anyone can help us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run Magento, you'll need a server environment running a web server (Like Apache and Nginx) and PHP.

[MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/) is an easy solution for this - It will install a local environment containing [Apache](http://www.apache.org/), [MySql](https://www.mysql.com/) and [PHP](http://php.net/)

**M**ac - **A**pache - **M**ySQL - **P**HP.